# Car travel time between two points swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking for something in swift that can give me the travel time (by car) of two coordinates. On some other threads, I have only seen suggestions to use external sources, but my question is, does apple have a built in feature to do this? Similarily, if there is not can someone please link a few external sources, as I have not found it (probably because I don't know exactly what I am looking for?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any Swift API solutions. Google has a great solution though. Check out Google's Distance Matrix API. It lets you calculate travel time for two coordinates with al sorts of extra options.

Comment: will look into it, thanks for responding.